# How can I remove a certain JCheckBox if it is selected?

Tags: java, swing

I am using an **Arraylist** for my Checkboxes. I want to **remove each one once it is selected** but my code isn't carrying out the expected behaviour. I don't know why my code isn't working.

Here it is:

```
public class sampledsa extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JCheckBox CBname;
    private ArrayList < JCheckBox > SBname = new ArrayList < > ();
    private JButton BTok;

    public sampledsa() {
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(500, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 1));

        BTok = new JButton("OK");

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            CBname = new JCheckBox("Checkbox" + (i + 1));
            SBname.add(CBname);
            add(SBname.get(i));
        }

        add(BTok);
        BTok.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource().equals(BTok)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < SBname.size(); i++) {
                if (SBname.get(i).isSelected()) {
                    SBname.remove(i);
                }
            }
            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            f.setVisible(true);
            f.setSize(500, 400);
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            for (int i = 0; i < SBname.size(); i++) {
                f.add(SBname.get(i));
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new sampledsa();
    }

}
```

Comment: Just a tip... Classes should start with uppercase letters and variables should start with lowercase letters.

Comment: I think `ArrayList` doesn't support concurrent modifications. That is, you can't remove elements while iterating it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/90/collections/2197/removing-items-from-a-list-within-a-loop#t=201608221144205738709

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others pointed out in the comment section you should not remove items of an `ArrayList` because you won't get the expected result.

You should use an `Iterator` instead.

Example:

```
Iterator<JCheckBox> iterator = sbname.iterator(); 
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
   JCheckBox checkbox = iterator.next();
   if (checkbox.isSelected()) {
      iterator.remove();
      //do some more stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: The whole point of using an iterator is the part that comes in the "do something" - which is removing the element using the iterator. Otherwise it's no different than a `for` loop.

Comment: @RealSkeptic added it to clarify it - thought it would be clear - my bad

Answer (score 0):

Use the modern Collection API.

```
SBName.removeIf(box->box.isSelected());
```

Or use a method reference.

```
SBName.removeIf(JCheckBox::isSelected);
```